# данные для vue-router после закрытия открытия браузера на странице отображаются в исходном виде

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

у меня есть фильтр, в процессе фильтрации в vue-router через axios загружаю данные и отображаю их.
однако после закрытия браузера и его последующего открытия я наблюдаю
[image: сырые данные пришедшие в json]

и если открыть консоль наблюдаю ошибку

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving
>   end does not exist.

Если смотреть в исходный код становится ясно, что vue не запустился.

Погуглив по этой ошибке - есть ответ, что это виновато расширение браузера 
 - однако и в chrome и mozilla одно и то же.

Предполагаю, что браузер сохраняет последние полученные данные на этой странице, а это как раз json, но почему-то не помнит о теле страницы. 
Значит необходимо каким то образом принудительно обновить страницу, но как это сделать, если тело сайта не загружено?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Браузеры кешируют все `GET` запросы. Поэтому здесь два варианта:

- Использовать другой метод запроса (например `POST`)
- использовать временную метку для ajax GET зарпосов. Т.е. к запросу добавлять query параметр с временной меткой. Например: `GET /api/endpoint?_=1223414141`;

Comment: Спасибо! А я наоборот на каком-то этапе решил, раз уж я делаю красивые ссылки в history api, значит можно делать get вместо post.

Comment: Можно, но добавляй query параметр)

Comment: но тогда ссылка не будет такой красивой как планировалось;(
site.tst/params/city_minsk-moskva/season_summer/

Comment: Я имел ввиду только `ajax` запрос. В ссылку ты можешь его не вставлять.

Comment: Ох, да, точно! Спасибо, огромное, за подсказки!